# how load messages.properties in test code when using MockMvc

Tags: java, spring, testing, spring-mvc

I make test codes for spring mvc test controllers with MockMvc. 
It's good! and but I have some problems for messages.properties.

I have registred "messageResource" to the applicationContext.xml. and I've checked this file with property-placeholder.

but, It's not working in the test code. but It's working in the web server. 
How do set the messages.properties to the MockMvc?

Here is my applicationContext.xml in my test codes.

```
<bean id="messageSource"
class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
<property name="basename" value="classpath:messages" />
<property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
```

and here is my test code. please help me.;

```
@Test
public void addUserWithPostToSuccess() throws Exception {
    MvcResult result = mvc.perform(post("/user/add/index").param("loginId", "LOGIN_ID").param("name", "NAME").param("password", "PASSWORD"))
                          .andExpect(status().isOk())
                          .andReturn();
    Map<String, Object> model = result.getModelAndView().getModel();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's solved. It's my mistake.;; 
The location of messages.properties file